# Swif / Cocoa / MacOS - How to stop key from being dispatched

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a global hot key for my application, but after it is called, it looks for the next letter clicked to change its behavior. The problem is that the letter still is typed into a text-editor if it is open. Is there a way to stop it from going through?

Edit: Here is the code I have so far:

```
let options = NSDictionary(object: kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as NSString) as CFDictionary
let trusted = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
if (trusted) {
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown, handler: self.handler)
}
```

The handler method:

```
func handler(event: NSEvent!) {
    let key = event.keyCode
    let flag = event.modifierFlags.rawValue
    if waitForNextLetter {
        waitForNextLetter = false
        // don't let this letter be dispatched
    }
    if key == 0 && flag == 655650 {
        waitForNextLetter = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry about that! I added the code in an edit. Do you know of a solution that could fix the issue?

Comment: What is `waitForNextLetter`? How do you use it? Don't show _some_ code; show the complete, minimal code needed to understand and reproduce your issue. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: From the documentation of `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`: Installs an event monitor that receives copies of events posted to other applications. You are unable to change the event, merely observe it. Events are delivered asynchronously to your app and you can only observe the event; you cannot modify or otherwise prevent the event from being delivered to its original target application.

Comment: What you're looking for is called an event tap.

Comment: As it was mentioned previously it's a monitor. The only way to be able to handle this is to override "keyDown". "black area": you can inject some library into target app that will do anything you want (e.g. swizzle keydown)

Comment: @MarekH is an event tap not an option?

Comment: @WillekeThanks. I learned something new! CGEventTapCreate documentation nicely explains it.